# If all the roots of a polynomial are characteristics roots of some matrix $A$ then the polynomial annihilates $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If all the roots of a polynomial are characteristics roots of some matrix $A$ then the polynomial annihilates $A$.

Comment: See the [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Comment: But @GitGud if all the roots of the polynomial equation $g(t) = 0$ be all eigen values of some square matrix $A$ then it may not contain all the distinct factors of the characteristics polynomial of $A$.Then how does $g(t)$ become a multiple of minimal polynomial because according to a well-known theorem of linear algebra it is clear to us that minimal polynomial should divide annihilating polynomial.Is n't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $p(x)$ the characteristic polinomial of $A$ and $q(x)$ a polinomial such that all the roots are characteristics roots of $A$.

So, $p(x)=q(x)h(x)$

By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem we have $p(A)=0$ but it doesn't garantee $q(A)=0$, so the statement is not true.

Example:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\ 0&-1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $p(x)=x^2-1$ and let's take $q(x)=x-1$ so we have $p(A)=0$ and $q(A) \ne 0 $.

Comment: Yes Arnaldo that is my point.